# how to display progress text in HTML5?

Tags: html, progress-bar

Here is my code in HTML

```
<progress min="0" max="100" value="10"><span>0</span>%</progress>
```

I can see the progress bar, but there is no text display. How can I make the text "10%" display on the bar without add new element?

What I can think of right now is using extral text to overlap on the top of the progress bar, such as

```
<progress min="0" max="100" value="10"></progress>
<div><span>0</span>%<div>
```

with CSS

```
div {margin-top: -20px}
```

I'm thinking of if there is better way to achieve it?

https://jsfiddle.net/etLv3z4b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pseudo elements in CSS (or at least that's the only way I know). That is, using `::before` and `::after`. Please refer to this handy article from [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/#article-header-id-6) to get my point.

I hope that helped.